# Project Euler Problem 783: Expected value of sum of squares

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I am trying to solve [Problem 783](https://projecteuler.net/problem=783) on Project Euler. I used a dynamic programming approach calculating the expected value given
a specific number of white and black balls.  Then E(n_w, n_b) (where n_w is the number of white balls and n_b is the number of black balls) can be calculated by conditioning on all possible values of the number of black and white balls removed after adding k black balls and this value is stored in a dictionary as d[(n_w, n_b)]. But dynamic programming takes too long to solve this problem. According to Project Euler, all problems follow the 'one-minute' rule, according to which they can be solved in 1 minute on a moderate machine. But on my computer the dynamic programming approach takes much longer and even for n = 10^3, k = 10 I stopped the execution after several minutes. Is there any other observation I am missing that can help speed up the code?

Comment: The Euler Project asks that you solve the problems independently.

Answer (score 0):

Since the white balls are all similarly situated, you can work from their perspective. Let $X_{i,t}$ be the event that white ball #$i$ is removed on turn #$t$. Then $B_t=2k-W_t$ where $W_t=\sum_{i=1}^{nk}X_{i,t}$.

\begin{align}
E(n, k) &= \sum_{t=1}^n \mathbb E\left[B_t(n, k)^2\right]\\
&= \sum_{t=1}^n \mathbb E\left[4k^2 -4kW_t + W_t^2\right]\\
&= 4nk^2 - 4k\mathbb E\left[\sum_{t=1}^n W_t\right] + \sum_{t=1}^n \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{kn} \sum_{j=1}^{kn} X_{i,t}X_{j,t}\right]\\
&= 4nk^2 - 4k^2n + \sum_{t=1}^n \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{kn} X_{i,t}\right] + \sum_{t=1}^n \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i\neq j}X_{i,t}X_{j,t}\right]\\
&= kn + kn(kn-1) \sum_{t=1}^n\mathbb E\left[X_{1,t}X_{2,t}\right]
\end{align}

The problem reduces to computing $\mathbb E\left[X_{1,t}X_{2,t}\right]$. This is just the probability that white balls #1 and #2 stay in the urn until turn $t$. Can you compute this probability?

Comment: E(2,2) = 9.6 but according to the expression E(2,2) >= 2*n*k^2 + k*n = 20

Comment: There were some algebra mistakes and I fix them.